# Why is there a "GC (Metadata GC Threshold) " before the "Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold)"?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

When I was investigating the GC log today, I found a strange phenomenon "GC (Metadata GC Threshold)" appeared before "Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold)". Could it be that a Minor GC occurred before the Full GC ?

My environment is:

```
# java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version
-XX:InitialHeapSize=268435456 
-XX:MaxHeapSize=4294967296 
-XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags 
-XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-XX:+UseParallelGC
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

The original log is:

```
2021-03-10T16:35:28.857-0800: 8.592: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006688 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000251 seconds
2021-03-10T16:35:28.870-0800: 8.606: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 62937K->10370K(87040K)] 102437K->53891K(291840K), 0.0078209 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.00 secs] 
2021-03-10T16:35:28.878-0800: 8.614: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 10370K->0K(87040K)] [ParOldGen: 43521K->47290K(204800K)] 53891K->47290K(291840K), [Metaspace: 56073K->55984K(1099776K)], 0.1764593 secs] [Times: user=0.97 sys=0.01, real=0.18 secs] 
2021-03-10T16:35:29.055-0800: 8.790: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.1847877 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000263 seconds
```

[original log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJNzS.png)

Comment: usually yes, a Full GC first triggers a young GC

Comment: yeah, but I only found that it appeared on "Metadata GC Threshold", and there was no Minor GC when the Full GC caused by "Ergonomics"

Comment: this might be an artifact of `ParallelGC`, `G1GC` does trigger a minor collection before a major one